# Horizontally centering a list with left-floated, left-aligned items

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` containing several `section`s. One of the `section`s contains an `ol`, and all of its `li`s are floated left. I am trying to make the `ol` shrink to contain as many `li`s as it can on one line, and horizontally center the `ol` while keeping the `li`s left-aligned.

**Here's what I have: http://jsbin.com/ocokog/1/edit**

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <section id="section">
  <ol id="list">
   <li id="i0"></li>
   <li id="i1"></li>
   <li id="i2"></li>
   <li id="i3"></li>
   <li id="i4"></li>
  </ol>
 </section>
</div>
```

Non-decorative CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 85%;
  text-align: center;
}

#section {
  display: inline-block;
}

#list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

#list > li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

When the `li`s can all fit on one line, the list is centered: [image: one line is centered]

When the `li`s fall onto a second line, the `section` and `ol` grow and the whole thing is left-aligned: [image: two lines are not centered]

I am trying to make it look like this (depending on the width available, also the `section` can shrink if necessary): [image: whole list should be centered regardless of number of lines]

Setting a width or max width and using `margin: auto` also doesn't quite work: http://jsbin.com/ocokog/6/edit

**Why won't the `ol` shrink? How can I fix this?**

---

These questions are similar but different:

- [Centering floating list items <li> inside a div or their <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235938/centering-floating-list-items-li-inside-a-div-or-their-ul) - in the accepted answer, all list items are centered
- [Can I center a <ul> with left-aligned <li>s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355058/can-i-center-a-ul-with-left-aligned-lis) - each item has its own line

Answer (score 0):

The `ol` is centered. You've set it to be `65%` width. If you look at the orange border when you re-size it, it's always centered.

#### Edit

Let me try to rephrase this a little.
`ol` is a block element, the same way that a `div` is a block element. This means that it fills up the space that it is in. This is represented by the orange border in your example. What you want, is for the `ol` to take up less than 100% of the space. There are many different ways to this, but you always start with the list taking up as much space as it can.

One of the ways is to set the width. The problem with this is that you don't want a fixed width. So you tried setting the width by using percentages. This doesn't work because there are many intervals where a percentage will cause the `li` to not be centered.

Another method would be to set the left and right margin's of the `ol`. This works the same as setting the width.

There just isn't a way to center something in an element that you also want to `float:left;`. I think the confusion comes in because you think that you can make the `ol` wrap around the `li`. The problem is, that isn't how the `ol` works.

Comment: I'm sorry, it looks like I meant 70%. I went straight to the link you provided [here](http://jsbin.com/ocokog/6/edit)

Comment: That was to show that setting a width won't work, as there's extra space that puts things off center. Contrast that with the last picture, which shows what I'm trying to do. I'm working from [this link at the top of the question](http://jsbin.com/ocokog/1/edit), but I'll make that more clear.

Comment: It does work though. The extra space is there because you're using percentages. You're almost always going to be off-center if you're using percentages with floats.

Comment: For example, try changing the percentage width of `#list` with `width:330px;`

Comment: I'd like to find a general case where it will use the width available, updated question again.

Comment: With just CSS, I don't think it's possible. You could try figuring out what the widths need to be at for the different intervals and change it with JavaScript.